# So close, but I can't seem to get a fixed footer with three columns to work…

Tags: html, css, footer, fixed

I apologize if this has been addressed elsewhere, but I've been looking all over and can't seem to figure this out.

I am trying to have three links across the bottom of the page which will be fixed, i.e. no matter how large the page or window is, they'll always be along the bottom, on a layer above the rest of the page content. I want one link to be left aligned, one to be center aligned, and one to be right aligned within the page margins (I set the body margins to 20px).

After a lot of fiddling around and trial and error, I have come pretty close, but I can't seem to get the proper margins around the text. I think it might be more clear if I just send a link to the page as it stands now—please disregard the colored backgrounds :)

http://www.chrissvensson.info/ces85/033

I have tried everything I can think of. If anyone has any suggestions, I would really really appreciate it. And feel free to tell me I'm going about this all wrong!

Here is the html:

```
<div class="bottom-nav">
    <h2 class="previous-link">Previous</h2>
    <h2 class="index-link">Index</h2>
    <h2 class="next-link">Next</h2>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.bottom-nav {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 -20px 0 -20px;
  background-color: red;
} 
.previous-link {
  width: 25%; 
  float: left;
  z-index:1999; 
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.index-link { 
  margin: auto;
  z-index:1999; 
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.next-link { 
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  z-index:1999; 
  text-align: right;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you wanted - http://jsfiddle.net/Ac3hD/1/

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the proper margins".

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. It's close. Sorry I wasn't more clear about the margins. I basically want there to be 20 pixel margins around the left, right, and bottom. In other words, I want the "Previous" link to have be aligned with the "Information" link at the top of the page. I guess by proper margins I meant, as though the text were abiding by the 20px margins I set in the body. 

I tried setting margin, padding, etc. inside the .previous-link but it messed with the width of the boxes, and either made the third box break onto a new line, or made the .bottom-nav div wider than the screen width…

Comment: I should mention that I originally had only two links—the "Previous" and "Next", and I just set them to fixed positioning like, left: 20px, bottom 20px, etc. and that seemed to work fine. I just couldn't figure out how to have the third "Index" link centered along the bottom, and fixed. If there's a way to do that, maybe I could just go back to having three separate divs, not contained in a larger 100% wide div? Just a thought… Thanks!

Comment: @user2188888 Can you make a jsFiddle showing your problem? I can't test it's alignment under the information link as it hasn't been given to me - http://jsfiddle.net/Ac3hD/2/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I just tried to make a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yU8fe/ My first time, so I hope I did it correctly. But if you visit the page I referenced (chrissvensson.info/ces85/033), the "Information link I mentioned is at the top left corner.

Comment: I just threw together a quick image that might be able to illustrate a little better what I'm going for: http://tinypic.com/r/5k58h1/5

Comment: I should mention also that the colored backgrounds were just for me to see the divs better when I was testing. The divs will have no background color, i.e. it will just be black text on the white page background…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add 
`.previous-link a {margin-left:20px}` or 
`.previous-link a {padding-left:20px}`, 
and the same on the other links. Like this you dont mess with the div so much but move link where you want it.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flex-box model. [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) says 72.93% of the web users at least partially support it, and that is a fairly large population. Check out its link to a flexbox playground.

If your clients are likely to have up-to-date browsers, it's a great choice. For those of your potential clients who don't have an up-to-date browser, you can just forward/link them to [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/10/dear-web-user-please-upgrade-your-browser/) and/or browsehappy.com. Or you could take advantage of browser-update.org's notification or updateyourbrowser.net's code.

An upgrade needs to happen sooner or later, the sooner the better.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that link. I'd never heard of flexbox, but I definitely want to try it out!